# jQuery animate step() stops animation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have the following code:

```
left = $('.academy-container').css('marginLeft');
function loop_forward(){
    $('.academy-container').stop().animate(
      {
        marginLeft:'-=20'
      }, 
      { 
        duration: 100, 
        step: function(now, fx) { 
          left = fx.pos; 
        }
      },
      loop_forward
      );
  }

  $('.carousel-next').hover(function() {
      loop_forward()
    }, function() {
      stop();
    })
  }
```

I'm trying to use the step function to keep track of the margin as it moves left by updating the "left" variable every step. However, it's not quite working how I thought it would. Instead of continuing the animation, it stops after 1 frame.

I want it to continuously loop through the animation while updating the variable as it goes. I can't find what's wrong with this code so any help would be appreciated. :)

Thanks.

Edit: here's a fiddle of the problem I'm experiencing:
http://jsfiddle.net/RhQrV/1/

Comment: Seems to [work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/RhQrV/).Your issue is probably with the code that accesses the `left` variable's value.

Comment: Updated the post with a fiddle of what I'm experiencing. I want be able to hover on an element, and have it keep moving (and this is where the step should be updating as long as I'm hovered).

Comment: Seeing as the first argument to `hover()` is an event handler for `mouseenter` and it has no notion of hovered time, if I understand correctly it may be easier to use some native APIs. http://jsfiddle.net/RhQrV/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *From your question:* However, it's not quite working how I thought it would. Instead of continuing the animation, it stops after 1 frame.
>
> *From your comments:* I want be able to hover on an element, and have it keep moving

Your animation is working fine and the **left** variable is being updated correctly and continuously.

However, your animation is configured to move the element only 20 pixels left over a duration of 100 milliseconds. Of course it would stop almost immediately - it's doing exactly as it's told.

If you want the animation to run continuously, you could use the animation's **complete** event to call itself. [Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RhQrV/6/). I've modified the mouseout function here to end the animation:

```js
$('.hover').hover(function() {
    loop_forward();
}, function() {
    $('.academy-container').stop(); // Stops the element's animation
});
```

The animation's configuration now looks like this, too:

```js
{
    easing: 'linear', // Ensure a smooth animation
    step: function (now, fx) {
        left = fx.pos;
        console.log(left);
    },
    complete: loop_forward // Animation now loops itself
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I knew I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are making an infinite loop and the browser don't like it. See, when i run you code, i get this error :

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

That's the error when you do an infinite loop. To much call for the CPU. You need to use Timer to make that loop :

```
var timer;

$('.hover').hover(function() {
    timer = setInterval(loop_forward, 100);
}, function() {
    clearInterval(timer)
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RhQrV/3/